# Does a SELECT statement make sense in a MySQL stored PROCEDURE?

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure, out, inout

My system: MySQL 5.6.12

Since you can't use a storede procedure in a SQL statement like a function, I'm wondering if there is any use for stored procedures which just have a SELECT statement but no OUT/INOUT parameter or do some manipulations.

Example:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp ()
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM tbl;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I can call the stored procedure like this:

```
CALL sp();
```

and it shows a result set in the IDE, but other than that I can't see any really practical usage for that.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe to clutter up the database with unnecessary stored programs Or maybe to increase complexity and obfuscation? OR maybe the intent is to add the ability to *modify* the SQL statement without modifying the caller. Or, maybe it's a placeholder for an enhanced procedure. Aside from that, I don't see any benefit to adding a procedure such as that. (Maybe this is an answer, and not a comment.)

Comment: What about having such a stored procedure to aid in debugging?

Comment: Even for debugging purposes I don't see any benefit to use this kind procedure over using the select statement directly or creating a view, if it has no IN parameter.

Comment: @spencer7593 with `IN` parameters it's useful in e.g. SQL Server. There you can use the result set within code not just show in Editor. But unfortunately MySQL is obviously not sophisticated for sp yet.

Comment: @John: A MySQL procedure can use IN and OUT parameters. A MySQL procedure can also define cursors, fetch the rows from it, and consume them within the procedure *without* returning the resultset to the caller. It's also possible to run a SELECT that returns a single row INTO procedure or user-defined variables, again, *without* returning the resultset to the caller. (My previous comment addressed a MySQL stored procedure that contains *only* a single, static SELECT statement that returns a single resultset to the caller. Is there a reason for it? Maybe. Is there a good reason for it? Unlikely)

Answer (score 0):

All it does is move the details of the query away from the caller (which is a valid thing to do, simplifies client-side code and eases schema migrations). You might as well use a view for that.

I'd only go for stored procedure if it needs to take parameters.

Comment: Even with `IN` parameters it stays the same:
 `CREATE PROCEDURE sp (IN id INT)
  BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tbl.id = id;
  END`

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. If it takes parameters, stored procedure can do it. View cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *just* a SELECT statement is pushing it; but there are plenty of valid reasons for parameterless Stored Procedures that return result sets. Thilo's answer mentions the main one; to enhance that...

If there were a specific result set frequently needed (such as some sort of monitoring/dashboard data) but too complex to fit into a VIEW, the data manipulation needed could be encapsulated in such a stored procedure, reducing the need for various clients to reproduce the same exact steps independently.